# "Once each" or "once every" six months?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, legalese, determiners

I'm formatting a bulleted list of benefits covered by a dental plan. I believe the text originally came from the insurance company's official "schedule of benefits" document, which is written in legalese. A bunch of the benefits are limited to "once each" some number of months, as in:

> - Bitewing X-rays once each six months
> - Study models and casts used in planning treatment once each 60 months
> - Periodontal surgery once per quadrant each 36 months

That sounds quite strange to me. **Is there a technical distinction between "once each *n* months" and "once every *n* months?"** I think the need for legal precision — or a fear of legal *im*precision — is the most plausible reason why someone might choose the unusual phrase "once each" over the more common "once every" or "once per," but I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Legal documents often uses ideosyncratic style, not the same wording that we use commonly. But they're equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "every 6 months" because "every" is used to refer to how often something happens.